# Shopify Python API - how to search for a product

Tags: django, shopify

I have built a django app that is the primary store for my products. From this, I publish products to my Shopify Store. Now my django app knows first when my product goes out of stock.

Question:
What options do I have to search for products using the Python API? Can I search by Title, Variant SKU?

Is storing the generated ID while publish the *only* means to get a handle on the product later?

I want to do this - so that I can mark the products Out Of stock, in a batch process, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing the product's id is the simplest way to get a handle on the product later.

However, the [product API](http://api.shopify.com/product.html#index) shows that you can filter products by vendor, handle, product_type, collection_id, published_status, updated_at, created_at or published_at.

The [Using the shopify python API](http://wiki.shopify.com/Using_the_shopify_python_api#Receive_a_list_of_all_Products) page shows how you can use these filters through keyword arguments to the find class method, e.g. `shopify.Product.find(collection_id=841564295)` to list products in a specific collection.

Answer (score 1):

YOu can use the official [shopify python API](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_python_api) to find a product with id:

```
shopify.Product.exists(product.id)  # => True
product = shopify.Product.find(292082188312)
```

For searching products with the product title, you can use [GraphQL API](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/graphql/reference/products-and-collections/product)